# Deploy Angular website as an Ionic App?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created a public facing Angular/Twitter Bootstrap website, and want to know if it's possible to wrap it as an Ionic App for android/ios ?

All the example  i have seen far shows the other way around, using ionic app as a website.Any pointers would be helpful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic is it's own framework, you wouldn't wrap it around a bootstrap/Angular app. I think you are interested in simply deploying your app to Android/iOS. In that case, check out http://phonegap.com/. It can bridge the gap by allowing you to deploy HTML websites as a native app.

If you wanted to use Ionic Framework, you should have developed it as a ground up first class Ionic app. Ionic provides deployment capability, but it simply leverages Cordova (which is the underlying technology of PhoneGap anyway)

Comment: Thank you ! are you saying using phonegap i can package my website as an apk file ?

Comment: Yes research that website and cordova documentation to understand how to do it. Good luck